# How to update the content of modal popup by closing another modal popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have two modal popups. Popup 1 is displayed to show the details of a dataset. To edit the data i am using a link to open another popup(2). Whenever popup 2 is closing i want to refresh the content of popup 1.

page(index.aspx)->popup1(partial.ascx)->popup2(partial2.ascx)

everything works fine except for refreshing the popup 1.

I am very new to javascript and jquery and i have no clue on how to accomplish this.
I already tried location.reload and opener.reload, but it only reloads the full page....

Here is my code:

---

View for popup 1:

```
`<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Change_Request.ViewModels.CheckOfMeasuresViewModel>" %>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "CheckOfMeasuresITDialog" }))
   { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <a href="#" style="margin-left: 20px;">Details</a></h3>
    <div>
        <div>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Add Measure", "Create", "Measure", new { id = Model.ChangeRequestID, nextView = "./../ChangeRequest2/Partial/_CheckOfMeasuresIT" }, new { @class = "openMeasureDialog", data_dialog_id = "CreateMeasureDialog", data_dialog_title = "Add Measure" })%>
        </div>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChangeRequestID) %>
        <div class="display-field">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Submit Date
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <% foreach (var item in Model.measures) %>
                <%{ %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.submitDate) %>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                <%} %>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table style="width: 95%; margin-top: 10px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.allMeasuresCompletedIT) %>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.allMeasuresCompletedIT) %>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.allMeasuresCompletedIT) %>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>`
```

Javascript for both popups:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });
});
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openMeasureDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>").addClass("MeasureDialog").attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id")).appendTo("body").dialog({
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"), close: function () {
                $(this).remove()
            },
            position: ["middle", 20],
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 850,
            maxheigth: 800,
            midth: 'auto'
        }).load(this.href);
    });
    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".MeasureDialog").dialog("close");
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

Controller for popup 2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MeasureViewModel _measure, string nextView)
{
    Measure m = new Measure();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Measures.Add(m);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("Partial/_CloseDialog");
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }
    ViewBag.ChangeRequestID = new SelectList(db.ChangeRequests, "ChangeRequestID", "initiator", _measure.ChangeRequestID);
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("Partial/_Create", _measure);
    return View(_measure);
}
```

Partial for closing popup 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".MeasureDialog").dialog("close");
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a fiddle or to a live example?

Comment: I can´t provide you a link, sorry. It is an intranet-page.

Comment: Just a heads up, you should get away from using .live() , its deprecated. It's good practice to use .on() instead.  http://api.jquery.com/on/  :)